# get "li" equal height by matching the same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please take a look at this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3sfy/3847/). I need to achieve equal height in the two unordered lists.  How can I get the heights of the `li` with the same class names (`description`,`year`,`package`,`location` etc) and compare, then give the shorter `li` the bigger value?

```
<div class="pricing-table">
                <ul>
                    <li class="heading">Bronze</li>
                    <li class="year">2003<p>(Text)..........</li>
                    <li class="package">Starter package</li>
                    <li class="location">Africa (Text).......)</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
</div>
<div class="pricing-table">
                <ul class="feature">
                    <li class="heading">Silver</li>
                    <li class="year">2004</li>
                    <li class="package">Intermediate package</li>
                    <li class="location">Asia</li>
                    <li class="description">Text............ </li>
                </ul>
 </div>
```

For example, get the `li`s with the same class name `description` and give the shorter one the height of the longer one. I find the following code is quite close to what I'm looking for, but it has to use different classes.

```
    $(document).ready( function(){
     var leftHeight = $(".left").height();
     var rightHeight = $(".right").height();
      if (leftHeight > rightHeight){ $(".right").height(leftHeight)}
         else{ $(".left").height(rightHeight)};
    })
```

Comment: If you want them all the same height then you are effectively creating a table. I would use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the LI's in the first list, find other LI's with the same className, get the max height and set the height of all of them to the same.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.pricing-table:first ul li').each(function(i, elem) {
        var elems   = $('.pricing-table ul li.' + elem.className),
            heights = $.map(elems, function(li) {
                return $(li).height();
            }),
            max     = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

        elems.height(max);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p3sfy/3849/)